# How use Eventhub and Storage SDK in python in Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-eventhub

How do people solve it when they want to use ADLS gen2 storage along with event hub in python SDK
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/8912

Comment: Hi Nipun, which feature of ADLS gen2 storage do you want to use? Can you provide a code example?

Comment: I would like to read file. I can use rest api for this, but was mainly interested in the sdk as it provides exception handling

Comment: You mean you're installing azure event hub package is 1.3.2, and want to use the latest blob storage sdk v12 to operate ADLS Gen2. If yes, I want to know one thing, when operate ADLS Gen2, there is nothing to do with event hub, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct me if I misunderstood your question.

1. If you installed [azure-eventhub 1.3.2](https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/1.3.2/), and at the same time you want to use the latest [azure-storage-blob 12.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/) to operate ADLS Gen2(I assume you just need to operate ADLS Gen2, but nothing to do with event hub). If that's the case, I suggest you can [create a virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html), then install the [azure-storage-blob 12.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/) within the virtual environment.
2. If you want to use the latest [azure-storage-blob 12.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/) with azure event hub, then the lower version of event hub is incompatible with [azure-storage-blob 12.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/), you should use the newer version of event hub, like [azure-eventhub 5.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/).

Comment: Oh I didnt realised that Azure-eventhub 5.0.0 is released. Seems like it is release recently.  I accept this as an answer